# system tray icon disappears while installing google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, skype, system-tray

Skype and network tray icon disappears after installing Google Chrome.

`sni-qt:i386` is already installed

My doubt is `libappindicator1` is getting uninstalled when Google Chrome is installed

While installing `libappindicator1`, `libappindicator1:i386` and `google-chrome:i386` are getting uninstalled automatically and tray icon comes back

System : ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Comment: Could not recreate this on 14.04.3 64bit, downloaded chrome installer from website, opened with software centre and it installed with out error, certainly no disappearing status icons, all I can suggest is make sure the system is up to date, first remove chrome, then do a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and reboot, now try installing Chrome again.

Answer (score 1):

To return icons I have just killed 'indicator-application-service' and icons network, bluetooth and skype appear again. I use xfce on amd64.

```
killall indicator-application-service
```

You may also try to install sni-qt package:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
```